# How to make an iron golem follow and protect me?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I need help making my iron golem follow and protect me on my Xbox 360. I hope you can tell me how to make them protect and follow me from enemies.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the Minecraft wiki and assuming you are speaking about Golem and not Glomen (that doesnt seem to exist) there is no thing like wheat for cows to make them follow you.

But you can use a leash to drag them to where you want them. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem